# Редирект со всех поддоменов *.site.ru на site.ru/*

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите пожалуйста сделать редирект со всех поддоменов *.site.ru на site.ru/*.
Например: test.site.ru должно перенаправить на site.ru/test.
Сервер Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.site\.ru$
RewriteRule ^ http://site.ru/%1 [R=301,L]
```